# Geometry / Calculus - relationship between surface area and volume of a burrito

Tags: sequences-and-series, volume

Basically, trying to find the relationship between the radius of the surface and the volume of a burrito as a (graph-able?) mathematical progression in terms of radius (or width) of the tortilla. For simplicity's sake, the tortilla can be square, the burrito can be an open cylinder, and the burrito has no layering in the wrap. I initially thought this was simply making the ratio between SA and Volume in terms of radius or width/height, but then realized I was using the radius of the cylinder. 
Sorry if this is a stupid question, sorry again if there's an existing question that answers this, and thanks for your help.

Comment: In general, $A = k\ell^2$ and $V = k'\ell^3$, where $\ell$ is a linear measure (length), $A$ is area, $V$ is volume, and $k$ and $k'$ are constants of proportionality.  It seems that your area is the surface area of a cylinder, and your volume is the volume of that same cylinder.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by constants of proportionality?

Comment: The volume of a sphere can be written as $\frac{4}{3} \pi \ell^3$ if we take $\ell$ to be the radius, or $\frac{1}{6} \pi \ell^3$ if we take $\ell$ to be the diameter.  In the first, case, the constant of proportionality is $\frac{4}{3} \pi$, while in the second case, it is $\frac{1}{6}\pi$.  In general, volume scales like the cube of length, but the *exact* relationship between volume and length is going to involve some constant.